# good spell checker for IE6?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, internet-explorer-6, spell-checking

Please suggest a spell checker for IE6.

Preferences (but not mandatory):

- open source
- free
- ajax-friendly

If you need clarification please leave a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- ieSpell (not open source, free for personal use, some programming interfaces)

It's actually an add in for IE not a server side thing (which because of your IE6 reference seems to be what you're looking for).